# How can I add the new id in the pandas DataFrame after every 5 rows,

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I add the new id in the pandas DataFrame after every 5 rows,

so my data is:

```
index            DateTime       A1   A2   A4        AMS  baseD       
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   
16610747    2011-01-03T13:15:59 112 103 368010037   128 003669730   
16610749    2011-01-03T13:17:00 95  90  368010037   128 003669730   
16610751    2011-01-03T13:18:00 75  67  368010037   128 003669730   
16610753    2011-01-03T13:18:59 42  33  368010037   128 003669730   
16610755    2011-01-03T13:20:00 14  7   368010037   128 003669794   
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   
16610747    2011-01-03T13:15:59 112 103 368010037   128 003669730   
16610749    2011-01-03T13:17:00 95  90  368010037   128 003669730   
16610751    2011-01-03T13:18:00 75  67  368010037   128 003669730   
16610753    2011-01-03T13:18:59 42  33  368010037   128 003669730   
16610755    2011-01-03T13:20:00 14  7   368010037   128 003669794
```

and what I need is an ID Column which will be incremental after every 5 rows

```
index            DateTime       A1   A2   A4        AMS  baseD      ID 
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   1
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   1
16610747    2011-01-03T13:15:59 112 103 368010037   128 003669730   1
16610749    2011-01-03T13:17:00 95  90  368010037   128 003669730   1
16610751    2011-01-03T13:18:00 75  67  368010037   128 003669730   1
16610753    2011-01-03T13:18:59 42  33  368010037   128 003669730   2
16610755    2011-01-03T13:20:00 14  7   368010037   128 003669794   2
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   2
16610745    2011-01-03T13:15:00 130 122 368010037   128 003669730   2
16610747    2011-01-03T13:15:59 112 103 368010037   128 003669730   2
16610749    2011-01-03T13:17:00 95  90  368010037   128 003669730   3
16610751    2011-01-03T13:18:00 75  67  368010037   128 003669730   3
16610753    2011-01-03T13:18:59 42  33  368010037   128 003669730   3
16610755    2011-01-03T13:20:00 14  7   368010037   128 003669794   3
16610755    2011-01-03T13:20:00 14  7   368010037   128 003669794   3
```

Comment: incremental for every 5 rows not columns it seems

Comment: ohh yes sorry, its rows I will edit my question, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate sequence of 1,2,3,.... for 5th percent of dataframe rows and repeat(np.repeat) each value for 5 times and assign as `ID` :-)

```
df['id'] = np.repeat(np.arange(np.ceil(len(df)/5),5)[:len(df)]
```

Comment: Thank you :-)  @pyd